# How to monitor prepared statement on DB2

Tags: db2

DB2 event monitor `STMT_TEXT` shows a query with "?" placeholder and does not show the value used to replace the "?" placeholder.

**Example Query:**

```
Select * from users where userId = ?.
```

Since the setInt was used to replace the placeholder with say, 1. I would expect a result as follows:

```
 Select * from users where userId = 1.
```

Is it possible to have `eventmonitor` return the query issued with values?

Comment: Care to mention your DB2 version and platform?

Comment: DB2 for LUW 8.x on Windows. Client windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in DB2 v.8. It will soon be five years since DB2 8 became unsupported. You should upgrade to a supported version, then you'll be able to use the activities event monitor to get the data you need.